# Can we use .pbtxt instead of .pb file in using Tensor flow model

Tags: android, python, tensorflow

I created a Tensorflow model which generated .pbtxt file. Can I use this file in building Android Application to use the generated model by renaming it to .pb file.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If the `.pbtxt` file is really a textual representation of the TensorFlow graph, then no, the Android APIs currently do not accept that and instead require a binary representation of the graph.

That said, if you have the `.pbtxt` file, you can easily convert it to a binary protocol buffer with a few lines of Python:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from google.protobuf import text_format

with open('/tmp/myfile.pbtxt') as f:
  txt = f.read()
gdef = text_format.Parse(txt, tf.GraphDef())

tf.train.write_graph(gdef, '/tmp', 'myfile.pb', as_text=False)
```

Alternatively, if you control the pipeline that generated the `pbtxt` file to begin with, perhaps you could change that to write out the file in binary format?

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks mate . I am able to generate .pb file now . But when I use this .pb file in my mobile app predictions are coming as zero

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can find your answer [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7172), but first you need the .ckpt file.

> the cmd to free graph for the model, pay attention to ouput node name, you can get it from .pbtxt file.

```
bazel-bin/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph --input_graph=/home/scopeserver/RaidDisk/DeepLearning/resnetv2.pbtxt --input_checkpoint=/home/scopeserver/RaidDisk/DeepLearning/slim/inception_resnet_v2.ckpt --output_graph=./inception_resetv2.pb --output_node_names=InceptionResnetV2/Logits/Predictions
```

You can run this command as a task of gradle in your Android app.

Comment: How do you find the output_node_names from the graph?

Comment: @Blue any idea on output_node_names?

Comment: I used tensorboard to study the graph and did it on a trial and error basis